# getAccounts undefined recently

Tags: metamask, accounts, web3js-v0.x

I've been using web3 v 0.20 and I recently noticed that getting `accounts` from

```
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
```

returns `undefined`.

Is Metamask 7.2.1 forcing it to be undefined for getting accounts now? It used to be okay last week though :(

[image]

Comment: In web3 v1.x, this function takes only one parameter, which is equivalent to your second parameter (`accounts`). Therefore, if you were calling it as shown in your question but under web3 v1.x, the second parameter would be undefined. I therefore conclude with a high degree of confidence that you are under web3 v1.x (and not under web3 v0.20.x as you think).

Comment: @goodvibration nah, see my update.

Comment: You wrote "returns `undefined`" at the top of your question, so please make up your mind `([] != undefined`).

Comment: @goodvibration apologies.. I got `undefined` from the `try/catch`. So any idea why `accounts` is empty please

Comment: Sure, non of your accounts is unlocked on the node that you're communicating with.

Comment: okay, but one more thing to add i'm running ganache and imported some of the accounts to metamask. Isn't accounts in ganache already unlocked?

Comment: Ganache unlocks 10 accounts by default (with private keys `0x0...1` thru `0x0...a`), unless you override this configuration when you start the process. I would guess that you're not connected to that process (Ganache node) at the time when you call the `getAccounts` function.

Comment: interesting.. i could import accounts from ganache to metamask now.. but one thing i noticed from metamask was that disabling `Privacy Mode` option in metamask has disappeared in the recent version. I had to disabled it to bring up my accounts in code before.  Would this be related? i guess `privacy mode` is default to `true` now in metamask